# How can i make flex-direction column dynamic with vutefyjs classes?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuetify.js

I am new to vuejs and i started with vuetifyjs. I am having problems with their layout.What i want to do is: i have four columns for example they have 4 width in the 12 layout grid. On same break point they will go one under another instead to be in same line

```
<template>
<v-container class="grey lighten-5">
    <v-row class="mb-6" no-gutters>
        <v-col v-for="n in 4" :key="n" cols="md-3">
            <v-card class="pa-2" tile outlined>
                col
            </v-card>
        </v-col>
    </v-row>
<v-container>
</template>
```

But they have always same width:

I need something like in bootstrap:

```
col-md-4
```

they will have 4 width until 768px,below that the columns will be one under another.

Is this possible with vuetifyjs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cols` prop is to set the default number of columns. Then use on of the breakpoint props (`sm`, `md`, `lg`, ...) to set the number of columns at that breakpoint.

Therefore, for full-width columns on mobile, and 4 columns on `md` and larger:

```
     <v-container class="grey lighten-5">
            <v-row class="mb-6" no-gutters>
                <v-col v-for="n in 4" :key="n" cols="12" md="3">
                    <v-card class="pa-2" tile outlined> col </v-card>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
     <v-container>
```

https://codeply.com/p/jhYKePIxal

Also note that [Vuetify's breakpoints](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/breakpoints/#display-breakpoints) are different than Bootstrap's breakpoints. "Medium" is `960px > < 1264px*`, and there isn't a 768px breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks for your response.Now it works.But the problem is  - i need to have 12 width when the screen is smaller then 1264px until the smallest devices. So i added md="12" sm="12 xs="12". md and sm are working but xs is not working and when the screen is <600 i still get 3 width for all 4 columns which is not good because it is not responsive....

Comment: There is no xs prop, that's what cols is for... extra small is the default (mobile) breakpoint. Did you see the Codeply? Please clarify the question. You didn't mention 1264 until now. If you want 4 columns on "lg" then change my example to `lg="3"`